# Confusion when finding joint density of $Y-X$

Tags: probability

I have the density $f(x,y) = 4 e^{-2x} $ for $0<y \leq x < \infty $ and $0$ otherwise. I want to find the density function of $Y-X$.

In other words, I want $P(Y-X \leq z ) = P( (X,Y) \in C ) $ where $C = \{ (x,y) : y \leq x+ z \} $. Thus ,

$$ P((X,Y) \in C) = \int\limits_{z}^{\infty} \int\limits_0^{x+z} 4 e^{-2x} dydx = \int_z^{\infty} 4(x+z) e^{-2x} dx= 2 z e^{-2z}$$

My answer key gives $2e^{-2z}$. Is my calculation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrectly taken $x$ from $+z$ to $\infty$ in the outer integral; rather we have $\color{red}-z<x<\infty$.

Because $$y>0,y-x\le z<0\implies x\ge y-z> -z$$

For each $z<0$, the *distribution function* of $Y-X$ is

\begin{align}
P(Y-X\le z)&=\iint_{y-x\le z}4e^{-2x}\mathbf1_{0<y<x}\,dx\,dy
\\\\&=4\int_{-z}^\infty\left\{\int_0^{x+z}e^{-2x}\,dy\right\}\,dx
\\\\&=4\int_{-z}^\infty e^{-2x}(x+z)\,dx
\\\\&=4\left[\int_{-z}^\infty xe^{-2x}\,dx+z\int_{-z}^\infty e^{-2x}\,dx\right]
\\\\&=4\left[\frac{1}{4}e^{2z}(1-2z)+\frac{ze^{2z}}{2}\right]
\\\\&=e^{2z}
\end{align}

Differentiating the above wrt $z$, the *density function* of $Y-X$ should be

$$g(z)=2e^{2z}\mathbf1_{z<0}$$

Not sure if you quoted the answer key correctly.

Comment: Im still confused why we need to start at $-z$?

Comment: @JimmySabater See edit.

Comment: @JimmySabater Was the reasoning clear? Keep in mind that $z$ is a negative quantity (the support of $Y-X$ is negative) and $x$ is defined over positive reals. So there is a contradiction if you start integrating from $z$.